# Adding an external project directory in phpStorm 6.0 to keeping workspace files separated from code?

Tags: phpstorm

I am try to keep separate workspace directory and code directories in my php project and sweating to understand/find how this could be achieved. A couple of revisions back I tried phpStorm and found that it does not provide such feature.

I just want to know if phpstorm 6.0 has  this feature or still lacking it ? If possible please help me out.

**Work Around**

File > Settings >[Directories]
     +[Add Content Root] to add external directory

Assuming that you have created project separate from code.Some of the tool might not work 
 as expected

Comment: Are you talking about having `.idea` folder separate to the actual code? If so -- manual workaround is there, it works: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-343

Comment: @LazyOne yes exactly I want that .idea folder separate from actual code. Thanks for the link

Comment: It is interesting that the bug is critical and open since 2009 and still not assigned to anyone and seems intellij is not interested in fixing this any more

Comment: It's not a bug -- it's **feature** -- there is nothing fundamentally wrong with current behaviour that would prevent IDE (or user) from doing its job. But yeah -- I have no idea why it has "critical" priority (in first place) ... and not implemented yet.

Answer (score 0):

This works for linux using sshfs, sorry for windows users.
 
 
I've created this folder structure in my pc 
 **/mnt/remote_code/code/** 
And i have to mount code from server like this 
 **sshfs user@server:/var/www/server_code/ /mnt/remote_code/code/** 

Code from server will be mounted in **code** folder
In PS I open this directory: **/mnt/remote_code/**

So, that means PS will create this folder **/mnt/remote_code/.idea** (indexing and saving all project and ide settings), and keeps the **code** folder (with remote code inside) without changes.

Hope it help you. 
Greetings.